# MongoDB with Koa JS: client.connect is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, koa, koa2

I am trying to develop my first simple app using Koa, which just recieves some data and puts it in a Mongo DB. However, I found it difficult even to connect to the database, as the response I get is `{"error": "this.db_client.connect is not a function"}`. Here is the app code:

```
import Koa from "koa";
import bodyParser from "koa-bodyparser";

import {DBHandler} from "./db"
import {error} from "./middlewares/error";

const app = new Koa();

app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(error);

app.use(async ctx => {
    const db = new DBHandler();

    db.writeEntity(ctx.request.body);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

The DBHandler:

```
export class DBHandler {
    constructor() {
        this.db_url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
        this.db_client = new MongoClient(this.db_url, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
    }

    writeEntity = (entity) => {

        console.log(this.db_client);
        this.db_client.connect((err, client) => {
            if (err) throw new Error("Connection Error");

            const db = client.db("database");
            const collection = db.collection("users");

            collection.insertOne(entity, (err, res) => {
                if (err) throw new Error("Insertion Error");

                console.log(res.ops);
                client.close;
            });
        });
    };
}
```

By the way, the `console.log(this.db_client)` prints `Promise { <pending> }`, which means, my MongoClient object is a promise!

Any ideas, what is happening and how to make it work?

Comment: `this.db_client` referencing a new `MongoClient` instance shouldn't be a promise. Are you using the MongoDB node driver [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/)? If yes, what version.

Comment: @OTZ I use version 3.4.1

Comment: Can you share the code snippet of how you are importing the `MongoClient` class?

Comment: @OTZ It's just `import MongoClient from "mongodb";`

Comment: Yh, I see. That's where the problem is. I would post an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you confirmed via the comments that you are importing the `MogoClient` like this:

```
import MongoClient from "mongodb";
```

I can confirm that is where the problem is, `MongoClient` is not a direct export of the `mongodb` module, instead, it's a sub export. You are supposed to import it like this:

```
import mongodb from "mongodb";
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

// Or using require
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
```

This should fix the problem.
You can read more on connecting to MongoDB with the `MongoClient` class [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/tutorials/connect/).